# reorder link in the order confirmation email magento 2

Tags: magento2

**How to add a reorder link in the order confirmation email Magento 2 ?**

I need to reorder the link in the email.

Answer (score 0):

To add a reorder link in the order confirmation email in Magento 2, you can follow these steps:

1. Override the email template:

   - Copy the order confirmation email template file `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/email/order_new.html` to your theme's directory: `app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{Theme}/Magento_Sales/email/order_new.html`.
   - Create the necessary directories if they don't exist.
2. Modify the email template:

   - Open the `order_new.html` file in a text editor.
   - Locate the section where you want to add the reorder link. Typically, it is placed after the order details section.
   - Add the following code to include the reorder link:

```html
<p>
    To reorder this order, please click the following link:
    <a href="{{var order.getReorderUrl()}}">Reorder</a>
</p>
```

3. Save the changes to the `order_new.html` file.

After following these steps, the reorder link will be added to the order confirmation email. When the customer receives the email, they can click on the "Reorder" link to quickly reorder the items from their previous order.

Remember to flush the cache (`php bin/magento cache:flush`) for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Is not working on magento 2.4.6.

Comment: @JigarPatel Could you please share the error details? I'm here to provide you with a proper solution.

Comment: i added "var order.getReorderUrl()" code on email template but reorder url is not set on a tag.

Answer (score 0):

To add a reorder link in the order confirmation email in Magento 2, you need to make some modifications to the email template and create a custom module. Follow the steps below:

1. Create a custom module:

   - Create the necessary module files and directories following Magento 2's module creation process.
   - Make sure your module is enabled and registered properly.
2. Create a custom email template:

   - In your custom module, create the directory `view/frontend/email` if it doesn't exist.
   - Copy the file `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/email/order_new.html` to your custom module's email directory.
3. Modify the custom email template:

   - Open the copied `order_new.html` file in your custom module's email directory.
   - Add the following code where you want the reorder link to appear:

     ```html
     <a href="{{var order.getReorderUrl()}}">Reorder</a>
     ```
   - Save the file.
4. Override the email template configuration:

   - In your custom module, create the file `view/frontend/email_templates.xml` if it doesn't exist.
   - Add the following code to override the email template configuration:

     ```xml
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
         <template id="sales_email_order_template" file="Vendor_Module::email/order_new.html" type="html" module="Magento_Sales" area="frontend"/>
     </config>
     ```
   - Replace `Vendor_Module` with the actual vendor and module names.
5. Clear the cache:

   - Run the following command to clear the Magento cache:

     ```bash
     bin/magento cache:clean
     ```

After following these steps, the reorder link should be included in the order confirmation email sent to customers. When the customer clicks on the reorder link, it will redirect them to the reorder page with the previously placed items in their cart, ready for checkout.