# How to add a reorder link in the order confirmation email Magento 2 using a custom controller

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

**How to add a reorder link in the order confirmation custom email template Magento 2 using a custom controller?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [reorder link in the order confirmation email magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/368169/reorder-link-in-the-order-confirmation-email-magento-2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Add the Reorder link to the order email need to create a new email template from the backend side or we already have the order email template then place the provided code in the email template.

```
<a href="{{store url=""}}your_controller/?order_id={{var order_id|raw}}">Reorder</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1 :**
If you have already created your order template, include the following line in that template:

```
<a href="{{var order.getReorderUrl()}}">Reorder the product</a>
```

**Case 2 :**
If you haven't created the order template yet, you can follow these steps to add the link in your Magento theme:

1. Go to your Magento Theme.
2. Override the file: **Magento_Sales->email->order_new.html.**
3. Do as suggested in **Case 1.**

Comment: Not Working on magento 2.4.6